# jQuery bootstrap datetimepicker field event

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using this [Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and i want to assign an event trigger when date has been chosen so that i can calculate the difference in another field

the problem is that if i use click like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.item',function(){
    ...
```

The user is not actually clicking the field but the datetimepicker windows that is actually out of the focus from this field...and i have also tried with

select
focus
change

they all kind a work but the user needs to click again or go over that field...in short additional actions are needed...

So the question is:

Is there some event trigger that can recognize the input field change?

Comment: The [`Events` documentation](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/) seems to suggest that `event.date` argument - "fired when the widget is hidden" - should contain the chosen date, and is available from the `toggle()`, `hide()` and `disable()` functions.

Comment: if you have Laravel?

Comment: Laravel has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I was thinking enough code here in your question that we can reproduce the problem in our own set-up and, ideally, a simple reproduction posted at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) (note the *and*, that minimal code must be in your question, the JS Fiddle is purely a bonus for ease of experimentation and development).

Comment: This is the answer on my question...the date time picker has it's own event listener dp.change and now it all works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to catch the change of the field of datetimepicker you need to use this command

```
$(document).on('dp.change', '.item',function(){ 
      . . .// your code
```

there is one more datitimepicker version and on that other one it's change.dp